# Sound and microphone not working properly, ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I was having issues where my microphone was not working, and I saw it advised to use pulseaudio, I tried running that but got:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

I tried solving that by looking at several already answered questions about that problem, however I did not manage to solve that problem, and now my microphone does not work still, and my laptop speakers don't do any sound when I do "test" in the settings, but they do work when I play a youtube video...

I am on ubuntu 20.04
My computer is an [asus gaming laptop](https://uk.store.asus.com/asus-tuf-gaming-fx705du-au035t-17-3-full-hd-slim-bezel-gaming-laptop-amd-ryzen-7-3750h-processor-16gb-ram-256gb-ssd-1tb-hdd-geforce-gtx-1660ti-6gb-graphics.html).
It has dual boot with windows 10.

I have just installed a new GPU nvidia driver because I got an external monitor that was showing blank (got it to work though!), don't know if that's of any relevance!

EDIT: Just checked if my bluetooth headphones worked, and the won't connect anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I also confirm that after upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04, I started facing sound problems.

E.g. while in Skype I'm able to use my headphones, when I select them via Settings - Sound and try Test, nothing can be heard.

I have the onboard soundcard and also the NVIDIA soundcard used to hear sound from my monitor's speakers.

Again, Sound Settings Test does not work properly for the Nvidia sound.